# Cannot login via username

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to login via `UserName` using `PasswordSignInAsync` but the result is even `False`, this is my code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(vm.Email);
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, vm.Password, vm.RememberMe, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong Credentials!");
        return View(vm);
    }
     return View(vm);
}
```

so essentially in my `View` I fill the email and password fields, and the `user` object is correctly filled with this information:

```
UserName = "some_username";
Email = "foo@gmail.com";
```

I tried to pass both `UserName` and `Email` in the first paramter of `PasswordSignInAsync` but I'm not able to fix this.

I saw also other similar question here, but I don't understand how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. Though, since you are already fetching the user, you can just use that directly:

```
await _signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, vm.Password, vm.RememberMe, false);
```

It's important to realize that this method can fail for multiple reasons, not just a bad username/password. 2FA may be required (`result.RequiresTwoFactor`) or the user could be locked out (`result.IsLockedOut`). Additionally, if you've required email verification, all login attempts will fail until the email is verified (`result.IsNotAllowed`). You should be checking for all these conditions and handling each appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looking at the table the field `EmailConfirmed` is true, the two factor is not enabled, so I really have not idea. I tried your code though, same problem

Comment: FYI, `IsNotAllowed` also applies to phone number verification.